# Is there any way to use setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode) in RemoteViews while working on app widget provider

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, remoteview

I am working on an android app widget. Where I've to use setColorFilter with mode PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY.

Currently I am using:

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.image, "setColorFilter", R.color.color_1);
```

where I only can tint with color. But I need to achieve this with using PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY as my resources supports this mode.

I've searched for a long time for a solution but couldn't find any. Can anyone enlighten me please.

Thanks.

Comment: no, you cannot do that

Comment: Then what's the solution in that case.

Comment: well, `setImageViewBitmap`?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: cheers bro :) @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sad that Android doesn't provide `setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)` or any method to tint view with `PorterDuff.Mode` in `RemoteViews` so far. At least I couldn't find one.